# CSS not working properly after Chrome browser update

Tags: html, css

I recently updated my google chrome browser i,e `Version 69.0.3497.81 (Official Build) (32-bit)`

After updation, my application dashboard's left menu is now hiding behind my the panel div as shown in screenshot
[image]

As shown in the above picture, the left navigation's `li (In red highlighted area)` is hiding behind the panel div.

After inspection, I got the code behind this

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px)
.sidebar-menu.collapsed .main-menu > li {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;

}
```

I tried z-index, but it is not working,Kindly suggest me the best solution

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] in the question?

Comment: it could be so many other things from different css(s), if you create this issue on jsfiddle and share, you'll get help from the community

Comment: @AIqbal better to use a snippet than a fiddle, then the code is in the question

Comment: @Pete that'll work too :)

Comment: From the looks of things, the containers of your content body and side nav that are on the the same level (go up the tree of each until you find the containers of each one that are siblings) are both positioned.  Give your side nav ancestor a z-index higher than your content body ancestor

Comment: Thank you pete, your suggestion works :)